# how to delete item from an array with filter?

Tags: php, arrays

I want to filter and delete an item from an array. is it possible to do it with array_filter() ?

```
//I want to delete these items from the $arr_codes
$id = 1223;
$pin = 35;

//Before
$arr_codes = Array('1598_9','1223_35','1245_3','1227_11', '1223_56');

//After
$arr_codes = Array('1598_9','1245_3','1227_11', '1223_56');
```

Thanks!

Comment: Is your criteria dynamic, or is it always `$id = 1223` and `$pin = 35`?

Comment: Dynamic objects, this is just an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find the index of the value you are interested in with [array_search](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) and then [unset](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php) it.

```
$i = array_search('1223_35',$arr_codes);
if($i !== false) unset($arr_codes[$i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

[array_filter](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) does not take userdata (parameters). `array_walk()` does. However, none of the iterator function allow modifying the array structure within the callback.

As such, `array_filter()` is the appropriate function to use. However, since your comparison data is dynamic (per your comment), you're going to need another way to obtain comparison data. This could be a function, global variable, or build a quick class and set a property.

Here is an example using a function.

```
array_filter($arr, "my_callback");

function my_callback($val) {
  return !in_array($val, get_dynamic_codes());
}

function get_dynamic_codes() {
  // returns an array of bad codes, i.e. array('1223_35', '1234_56', ...)
}
```